# Optimistic way to do database replication in same aurora rds

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

I have a mysql database db_1 in aurora-rds now daily I need to replicate(incremental backup) db_1 data (whose size is 50GB) to new database db_2 in same aurora-rds.

I used sql workbench and mysqldump command to get .sql file but it affected the cpu utilization to 100% and rds was on hang mood which was not the best way.

I wanted to know is there any optimistic method to perform data replication daily by which will not affect the CPU utilization so that my db_1 will be running good.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an Aurora DB, it already should have a backup. The default retention period for this is 1 day but you can always change this by modifying the `backup retention period`.

If you need to keep the backups for whatever reason after this then you can always take a snapshot and move it to somewhere like S3.

This link should help you out a little more: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Managing.Backups.html

Comment: Daily I need to push oly data from database db_1 to db_2 in same RDS and use db_2 for my testing